# How to pass params to `$scope` function from directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs

**IN CASE IF I AM WRONG SHOW ME THE CORRECT WAY TO DO IT**

I am trying to pass the `index` and `item` name from `ng-repeat`. it not working by some issue. can any one help me to sort this please?

here is the code :

```
<div class="wrapper" ng-app="myApp">
      <div class="content" ng-controller="main">
      <h2 ng-class="active">{{activeItem.name}}</h2>
      <sub-title  item='item' index=$index ng-repeat="item in items" change="changeItem()"></sub-title>
    </div>
    </div>

// Code goes here

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('main', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  console.log("cotroller")
  $scope.items = [{"name":'one'},{"name":'two'},{"name":'three'}, {"name":'four'},{"name":'five'},{name:'six'}];
  $scope.activeItem = $scope.items[0];
  $scope.queueItems = $scope.items.splice(0,1);

  $scope.changeItem = function (index, item) {
    console.log("change now", index, item.name); //not consoling
  }

}]);

app.directive("subTitle", function () {

    return {
      replace:true,
      scope:{
        change :'&',
        item : '=',
        index:'='
      },
      template : '<h2>{{item.name}} {{index}}</h2>',
      link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var num = scope.index;
        element.on('click', function () {
          scope.change(num, item); 
        })
      }
    }

})
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/kuFw1TXMJsqcKFgvlLy9?p=preview)

Comment: Please show us your html markup

Comment: please check, I have added the live demo

Comment: `h2` doesn't have change event. What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: on click of `h2` i would like to update the `$scope.activeItem` there in scope.

Comment: try `change="changeItem"`, i mean without parenthesis

Answer (score 2):

In this case you should pass a function reference by `=` binding, otherwise **you'd not be able to run an outside function with parameters from the inside of the directive**. So change your code a bit, like this:

```
app.directive("subTitle", function () {

    return {
      replace:true,
      scope:{
        change :'=',
        item : '=',
        index:'='
      },
      template : '<h2>{{item.name}} {{index}}</h2>',
      link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var num = scope.index;
        element.on('click', function () {
          scope.change(num, scope.item);
          scope.$apply();
        })
      }
    }

})
```

Bear in mind, that if you're running a function like this (triggering it by a DOM event, and not by Angular), the framework doesn't know about the fact that you've just run it. Therefore you have to trigger Angular's digest loop at the end, hence the `scope.$apply();`

(*I've also fixed the reverence to `item`, because it's declared on `scope` object so `scope.change(num, scope.item)` instead of `scope.change(num, item`)*

And then in your template declare it like this:

```
<sub-title  item='item' index=$index ng-repeat="item in items" change="changeItem"></sub-title>
```

Here's the working code: http://plnkr.co/edit/ECu9n0BS4XSqs1756h0v?p=preview

Comment: I am trying to update the data, but not works. http://plnkr.co/edit/kuFw1TXMJsqcKFgvlLy9?p=preview - I am trying to interchange the data

Comment: Angular doesn't know that you have run a function. Add `scope.$apply();` in the directive at the end of '`on click` handler. I'll update my answer in a second.

Comment: Not the one referenced in my answer (I left it to be in sync with code in your original question). But I've made another fork of your updated code here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jzc7cubGo5WZ6JzDZDde?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use $rootScope.$broadcast for calling function of controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('main', ["$scope", function($scope) {
  console.log("cotroller")
  $scope.items = [{"name":'one'},{"name":'two'},{"name":'three'}, {"name":'four'},{"name":'five'},{name:'six'}];
  $scope.activeItem = $scope.items[0];
  $scope.queueItems = $scope.items.splice(0,1);

  $scope.changeItem = function (index, item) {
    console.log("change now", index, item.name); //not consoling
  }
$scope.change=function(){
//your logic
}
$rootScope.$broadcast('msgFromDirective',function(evnt,data){
$scope.change(data.Num,data.Item);
});
}]);
```

Directive

app.directive("subTitle", function ($rootScope) {

```
return {
  replace:true,
  scope:{
    change :'&',
    item : '=',
    index:'='
  },
  template : '<h2>{{item.name}} {{index}}</h2>',
  link : function (scope, element, attrs) {
    var num = scope.index;
    element.on('click', function () {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('msgFromDirective',{Num:num,Item:item});            
 //  scope.change(num, item); 
    })
  }
}
```

})

Answer (score 1):

In your html pass function reference without paranthesis.

```
<sub-title  item='item' index=$index ng-repeat="item in items" change="changeItem"></sub-title>
```

Because we passed the function reference, `scope.change()` will not call the function but return the `changeItem` function.

```
scope.change();
```

Above call will return:

```
function (index, item) {
    console.log("change now", index, item.name); //not consoling
}
```

So you must first make a call to retrieve function, than call the actual function.

```
scope.change()(scope.num, scope.item); // calls changeItem function
```

Check this **[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/Fnc4nLk4dOxbDYnhb5HU?p=preview)**, I have edited your code.

Comment: but when i try to update the data not working : ` $scope.changeItem = function (index, item) {
    $scope.activeItem = item;
  }`